# How to make a single button act as a Start and Stop button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an image move when the user click the Start button, and the button then becomes a Stop button. at first I had 2 buttons but want it to be a single button.

This is what I have right now.

Html

```
<div><img id="myImage" src="car.gif" /></div>
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="startStop()" id="startButton">
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop()">
```

JavaScript

```
function init(){
imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
imgObj.style.position= 'relative';
imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}

function startStop(){
moveRight();
change();
}

function moveRight(){
imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
animate = setTimeout(moveRight,50); 
}

function change(){
var elem = document.getElementById("startButton");
if (elem.value=="Stop") elem.value = "Start";
else elem.value = "Stop";
}

function stop(){
clearTimeout(animate);
}

window.onload =init;
```

When I click the actual Stop button it stops the image dead on its tracks and when I click Start it resumes which I want to do all in one button. Also, How would I make it so after the image exits on the right, it re-enters from the left?

I was trying to add the `clearTimeout(animate);` between the `function change()` but that just made the buttons disappear. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to declare some global variables to see if animation is started or not, The updated code is,

**HTML**

```
  <div><img id="myImage" src="http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/8z26s5wwt04ersuf3wnj.jpg" /></div>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="javaScript:startStopImg()" id="startButton">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var imgObj;
var animate = null;
function init(){
    imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
    imgObj.style.position= 'relative';
    imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}

startStopImg = function(){
    if(animate != null){
        stop();
    } else {
        moveRight();
    }
   change();
}

function moveRight(){
imgObj.style.left = (parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10) + 'px';
animate = setTimeout(moveRight,50); 
}

change = function(){
var elem = document.getElementById("startButton");
if (elem.value=="Stop") elem.value = "Start";
else elem.value = "Stop";
}

stop = function(){
    clearTimeout(animate);
    animate = null;
}
window.onload = init();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/67ct5sre/20/)

Update
Just move the method change out of if-else in the startStopimg method, I have updated same in above code,
Updated [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/67ct5sre/21/)

Comment: Looks great! but when I click start the first time it changes to stop however when you click stop again it doesn't change to start until you click it one more time. You have to double click it to change. why ? =/

Comment: Ahh i saw the change, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it weird that it doesn't run when I copied the code to my .js file? It works on jsfiddle but doesn't seem to when I run the html file on my computer.

Answer (score 7):

Bind 2 *eventListeners* for `click` event on the same element, and remove one when another is fired.

Try this, it's just a demo code

***Html :***

```
<input type="button" id="mixBut" value="Start" />
```

***javaScript :***

```
var mixBut = document.getElementById("mixBut");

mixBut.addEventListener("click", Start);

function Start(){
    console.log("Started");
    mixBut.removeEventListener("click", Start);
    mixBut.addEventListener("click", Stop);
    mixBut.value = "Stop";
}

function Stop(){
    console.log("Stopped");
    mixBut.removeEventListener("click", Stop);
    mixBut.addEventListener("click", Start);
    mixBut.value = "Start";
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/cgh8xuv1/)